# Missing keyword error ora-00905

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

```
select line_number, TIME

from LINE join LINE_STOP join PASSAGE

where time = (select count (Time)

from passage

where time between 500 and 620)

group by line_number;
```

Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: `from LINE join LINE_STOP join PASSAGE` are you trying to join three tables?you miss the ON clause that identifies the columns that is the same in your table

Comment: There are too many problems in this query to make a suggestion:  `time` is an Oracle reserved word.  The `on` keyword is missing from the `from`.  You are comparing a column called `time` to a count, which seems unreasonable.  The `group by` does not agree with the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon Linoff  Correction!! TIME is a PL/SQL Reserved Word in Oracle and it can be used for SQL queries that are independent of PL/SQL Code. But in here, equating time with count value does raise a confusion. My guess, Valerie is trying to use it for counting the number of times, the line_number repeats or something like that.

And the 'missing keyword' error is because u were not using 'ON' keyword which is mandatory if u r using a Join statement.

@Valérie Hallé  Try this if u r trying to do like what I presumed above,

```
SELECT L.LINE_NUMBER, L.TIME
  FROM LINE L
  JOIN LINE_STOP LS ON LS.LINE_NUMBER = L.LINE_NUMBER 
  JOIN PASSAGE P    ON P.LINE_NUMBER = L.LINE_NUMBER
 WHERE L.TIME IN (SELECT COUNT (TIME)
                    FROM PASSAGE
                   WHERE TIME BETWEEN 500 AND 620);
```

This should work. If not, get back to me :-)

Comment: Yes i'm trying to count the number of time a bus passes at a stop.

Comment: this is what i have now but it's still not working! Thank you for your help!

Comment: SELECT LINE_NUMBER, TIME
  FROM LINE
  JOIN LINE_STOP  ON LINE_NUMBER = LINE_NUMBER 
  JOIN PASSAGE     ON LINE_NUMBER = LINE_NUMBER
 WHERE TIME IN 
    (SELECT COUNT (TIME)
      FROM PASSAGE
      WHERE TIME BETWEEN 500 AND 620) on
               (select Hours||''||Minutes as time
                from passage);

Comment: I think the query I provided is verified. If u can tell exactly what u need, I can u provide a solution on the same

Comment: this is my homework question: display the number of buses needed for each bus line.

Comment: what are you trying to imply exactly? At first, you specified that you are trying to count the number of time a bus passes at a stop and now the question u working on a solution is different. Valerie, you must be very clear on what needs to done.